# CSS_Menu_Walker not showing on mobile view?

Tags: menus, css, walker

I found this example on perishable press. My menu works fine and all the submenu items display properly. For some reason, when scaled below 769px, it disappears. I figure it's CSS, but I can't make the menu display the way on mobile views.

Here's my code...

```
class CSS_Menu_Walker extends Walker {

var $db_fields = array('parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id');

function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul>\n";
}

function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
}

function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {

    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';
    $class_names = $value = '';
    $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

    /* Add active class */
    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
        $classes[] = 'active';
        unset($classes['current-menu-item']);
    }

    /* Check for children */
    $children = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'nopaging' => true, 'numberposts' => 1, 'meta_key' => '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', 'meta_value' => $item->ID));
    if (!empty($children)) {
        $classes[] = 'has-sub';
    }

    $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item, $args));
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args);
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr($id) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr($item->attr_title) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty($item->target)     ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target    ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty($item->xfn)        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr($item->xfn       ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty($item->url)        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr($item->url       ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><span>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</span></a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
}

function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $output .= "</li>\n";
}
}
```

And this is where I show the menu in my header file

```
<div class="main-navigation">
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
'menu' => 'Main Menu', 
'container_id' => 'cssmenu', 
'walker' => new CSS_Menu_Walker()
    )); ?>
    </div>
```

I'm guessing that it's CSS because the menu appears and displays perfectly and aligned correctly with desktop views. When I change my media query for '768px' to display the menu, it shows the whole thing stacked, but not collapsed the way mobile menus normally appear in WordPress.

```
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
header {width: 767px; background-repeat: repeat-y;
height: initial; background-image: none;
background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.55); }
.main-navigation .menu {width: 767px;}
.main-navigation .menu li {width: 100%; display: none;}
.main-navigation .menu li a {width: 98%; text-align: left;
padding-left: 15px;}
```

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: There is not "normal appearance for mobile menus in WordPress". How the menu is displayed is totally up to you and your CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: OK fair point. The collapsable menus are theme driven but the point is that no menu shows up with the viewport is below 768px...

Comment: Maybe because of `.main-navigation .menu li {width: 100%; display: none;}` (note the `display: none`). I'm sorry but it seems that your question is out of the scope of this site. [Generic CSS questions are off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @cybmeta Thank you for your reply. i saw that too. It shows the entire expanded menu but I'll work from there. I tried to generalize my issue to a basic CSS question even though my question is about a WordPress site. If it was strictly PHP and CSS, I could code it all manually. I'll do better in relating future questions to WP...